Why do I get an error when I try to cast a user-input float into an integer, but not when I try to cast an integer into a float?
In Python, when I try to cast a float input by the user into an integer, I get an error.
This is the code:
x=int(input("Choose a number: "))

Then I input a float (3.0 is what I put), and I get this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.0'
But when I try to cast an integer input by the user into a float, it works perfectly fine. This is the code for that
x=float(input(Choose a number: "))

Then I put in an integer (three in my case), and it casts it and stores the value without a problem
When I initially got the error from trying to cast the float into an integer, I tried the opposite, like I said above, casting an integer into a float. I thought this would also result in an error, but it didn't, and it cast the integer like I initially expected it would have done to the float. I am left wondering why it works one way but not the other.

Because converting from a float to an int is a destructive rewrite, where the original input is unrecoverable from the conversion result, whereas converting from an int to a float is perfectly safe with the original input being perfectly recoverable from the conversion result.

Please always put the complete error message you get, including traceback, into your question as formatted text. This is incredibly more helpful than stating that you get "an error".

This question is similar to: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Friedrich, seems like maybe Capocho failed to understand that input(...) returns a string. The question that you suggested as a possible duplicate does not mention input(...).

From what I understand, the Input() function by default returns the data in the form of a string, and the int() function expects a number or a string with no dots (.).
Try this:
x = int(float(input("Choose a number: ")))

Here is another question that has the same issue as well:
int() not working for floats?

int(float("3.0")) is fine; int("3.0") is not. int expects a number or a string containing an integer.


Why do I get an error when I try to cast a user-input float into an integer, but not when I try to cast an integer into a float?

You are mischaracterizing the problem:
For example, the int(...) in
  int(input("Choose a number: "))

is casting a string to an int.  Not a float to an int.  The input function reads characters (up to the next end-of-line) and returns them as a string.
And ... obviously ... not all sequences of characters can be converted (meaningfully) to an int or a float.

"3" is a valid representation for an int or a float.
"3.0" is a valid representation for a float but NOT for an int.

So int("3.0") will give the error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.0'

Why?  Because that's how the int(...) function is defined in python.
But why?

Because converting a floating point string to an integer value potentially loses data.  Any digits after the decimal are lost, and the fact that the number may have been indicated as being imprecise is lost.
And when it happens, it is most likely due to a mistake: either a programming error or a (user?) data entry error.  Just like int("fish") would be a mistake ...

This also makes sense from a mathematical perspective.  If you equate int with integers and float with real numbers, the integers are a subset of the reals, not vice versa.  (Admittedly, equating float to real numbers has other problems ... but that's a different problem.)
In short, it all makes sense when you understand that:

input(...) is returning a string, and
python is not allowing conversion of arbitrary strings to int to protect against mistakes.

